# Cutting shape out image to show underlying image

Tags: html, canvas

I have two images, a gameboard and the same gameboard with all posible player positions in a pressed state. When a player moves to a position on the board, I put the board image over the pressed board image and slice using context.drawImage() on the pressed image, to display the pressed position through the slice. However, my game board contains positions which are not rectangular but different shapes.

Is it possible with html 5 canvas, to cut a non-rectangular shape out of an image to display the underlying image?

I found it's possible to use clip() on shapes but I can't find a similar option on images.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a third image that is a mask with transparent (alpha-channel) pixels and non-transparent pixels, and use a

```
 globalCompositeOperation
```

[to merge the mask and the to-be-masked image into a new image](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) ( think you can use an xor or source-out here..